# Git #hashtags in status

Tags: linux, git

I moved between two machines and now all my `git status` commands outputs are filled with `#`

I have the same `.gitconfig` and `.bashrc` files.

Also tested making a new git clone, same happens.

On my old computer it looks normal:

```
On branch xxx
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/xxx'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   xxx
```

On my new computer it's full of "comments":

```
# On branch xxx
# Your branch is up to date with 'origin/xxx'.
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       modified:   xxx
```

How do I remove those tags?

Comment: Is any command output prefixed with `#` and a space? Are you using any terminal managers, like `screen` or `tmux`? Is this the output of `git status`? Please post the output of `type git`, `/usr/bin/git status` and `/bin/sh -c 'git status'` on the new computer. Is there a missing line before `# Changes`? What is the difference in `env` between matchines? Would `git status >&2` output also be prefixed with `#`? What distribution are you using on that "new computer"? What shell are you using?

Comment: `type git` - `git is hashed (/usr/bin/git)`, the rest all has the same # output, and no missing lines. no other bash commands has #, not even git itself, like `git branch` and `git diff` prints just fine. both computers are centos 7, using bash @KamilCuk

Comment: Well, then `git --version` on both computers? I have `git version 1.7.10.4` that just prints `#`...

Comment: oh wow could be it! new one is `1.8.3.1` while old is `2.22.0`

Comment: @KamilCuk yep, I updated git and the # went away! post an answer I'll accept it

Comment: Note that `1.8.3.1` is 8 years old (June 10, 2013)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Older git versions just printed `#` in front of the lines in `git status` by default. And it was removed in newer version.

See https://github.com/git/git/commit/2556b9962e7c0353d562b7bf70eed11d8f29d0b0#diff-21ecaaf4e2318a39cdedf505941dbfbabd3329f041c839a03fb84906b4dae4fb this commit.

> status: disable display of '#' comment prefix by default
>
> Historically, "git status" needed to prefix each output line with '#'
> so that the output could be added as comment to the commit message.
> This prefix comment has no real purpose when "git status" is ran from
> the command-line, and this may distract users from the real content.
>
> Disable this prefix comment by default, and make it re-activable for
> users needing backward compatibility with status.displayCommentPrefix.
>
> Obviously, "git commit" ignores status.displayCommentPrefix and keeps
> the comment unconditionnaly when writing to COMMIT_EDITMSG (but not
> when writing to stdout for an error message or with --dry-run).
>
> Signed-off-by: Matthieu Moy Matthieu.Moy@imag.fr Signed-off-by:
> Junio C Hamano gitster@pobox.com

Comment: Nice find! I wasn't even aware as I always had the new git it seems.